# how to disable canvas xpress menu

Tags: javascript, canvas

i use `canvaXpress` on my webpage, it's a very good graph control, but i don't want to show customer the menu of `canvas xpress`, like help, show code, filter data on top right corner, how to disable it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. It would be helpful if you could provide relevant code that you have written or explain what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [**RTFM**](http://canvasxpress.org/events.html). It is called **Toolbar** and you can disable it by:

```css
#canvas1-cX-Toolbar {display: none !important;}
```

Or use the [API](http://canvasxpress.org/events.html) to disable it:

- `disableMenu` type: `boolean`
  Flag to disable showing the menu on right clicks
  **Default:** `false`
  **Used in:** all visualizations
- `disableToolbar` type: `boolean`
  Flag to disable showing the toolbar
  **Default:** `false`
  **Used in:** all visualizations